# mysql cardinality of column index is larger than unique values in that column

Tags: mysql, indexing, cardinality

I'm using MySQL 5.6. There is a MYISAM table with 1 million rows. The 'county' column in this table has a BTREE index on it, and the column only has 61 possible values. When I run 'show index in TABLE' on this table, it reports that the cardinality of the index on the 'county' column is 117554.

I am expecting the cardinality of a column index to reflect the number of unique values in the column. The numbers are very different in this case -- is that indicating some kind of problem, like a corrupted index?

I have run 'optimize table' and it does not change the cardinality of this index.

Answer (score 0):

The MySql documentation on indexes states:

> Cardinality
>
> An **estimate** of the number of unique values in the index. To update
>   this number, run ANALYZE TABLE or (for MyISAM tables) myisamchk -a.
>
> Cardinality is counted based on statistics stored as integers, so **the
>   value is not necessarily exact** even for small tables. The higher the
>   cardinality, the greater the chance that MySQL uses the index when
>   doing joins.

The bolded emphasis is mine. A lot goes into calculating cardinality on an index, including server memory availability and disk space.

I wouldn't focus on the cardinality calculation not being correct, especially since you have already run the `optimize table` command. Instead, check to make sure your queries are utilizing the index by running explain plans on your queries.